# com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting found for key 'play'

Tags: scala, playframework, key, config, typesafe

I work in a sbt project, and i am using library play-ws.
but my application does not play framework.

So, when i run mi Job, i have this error:

> com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting
>   found for key 'play'
>
> com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$Missing: No configuration setting
>   found for key 'play'  at
>   com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.findKey(SimpleConfig.java:124)
>     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:145)
>     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:159)
>     at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.find(SimpleConfig.java:164)
>     at
>   com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getObject(SimpleConfig.java:218)
>     at
>   com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:224)
>     at
>   com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.getConfig(SimpleConfig.java:33)
>     at
>   play.core.Invoker$$anon$1.play$core$Invoker$$anon$$loadActorConfig(Invoker.scala:35)
>     at play.core.Invoker$$anon$1$$anonfun$3.apply(Invoker.scala:23)     at
>   play.core.Invoker$$anon$1$$anonfun$3.apply(Invoker.scala:21)  at
>   scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)  at
>   play.core.Invoker$$anon$1.create(Invoker.scala:21)    at
>   play.core.ClosableLazy.get(ClosableLazy.scala:51)     at
>   play.core.Invoker$.system(Invoker.scala:40)   at
>   play.core.Invoker$.executionContext(Invoker.scala:41)     at
>   play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution$.defaultContext(Execution.scala:15)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution$Implicits$.defaultContext(Execution.scala:12)
>     at
>   play.api.libs.ws.ning.NingWSRequest$$anon$2.onBodyPartReceived(NingWS.scala:322)No
>   configuration setting found for key 'play'    at
>   com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.updateBodyAndInterrupt(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1568)
>
> at
>   com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.access$2900(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:161)
>     at
>   com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider$HttpProtocol.handle(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:2233)
>     at
>   com.ning.http.client.providers.netty.NettyAsyncHttpProvider.messageReceived(NettyAsyncHttpProvider.java:1227)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.stream.ChunkedWriteHandler.handleUpstream(ChunkedWriteHandler.java:142)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:459)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.callDecode(ReplayingDecoder.java:536)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.replay.ReplayingDecoder.messageReceived(ReplayingDecoder.java:435)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.handler.codec.http.HttpClientCodec.handleUpstream(HttpClientCodec.java:92)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:318)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
>     at
>   org.jboss.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

(I use sby assembly to make a jar and execute the job in spark job-server)
I dont use files configuration(application.conf, reference.conf, etc) in my job.

Please help me.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know what was causing the problem.

The following fixed it:

```
val parsedConfig = ConfigFactory.parseFile(new File("src/main/resources/application.conf"))

val conf = ConfigFactory.load(parsedConfig)
```

Comment: Thank you man, I had the same problem and this fixed it. Please consider accepting your own solution.

Comment: Where do the above "val parsedConfig =..." go? What uses "val conf"?